# Update field: Exception when invoking the method - Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

What I want to do is update a field called name, by means of its identification I do the query of the field.

When doing the name query, it takes me to the template called updatename.

The problem is that when I save the changes it tells me this message in the console.

**Exception while invoking method 'name.update' Error: Invalid modifier. Modifier must be an object.**

**Client**

updatename.html

```
<template name="updatename">
        <form class="editor-container">

          <input class=“save” type="text" id="card" value=“{{name}}”>

          <button type="button" class=“save” id="save">save</button>

        </form>
</template>
```

updatename.js

```
Template.updatename.events({
  'click .save’: function (e, t) {
       e.preventDefault();

       FlowRouter.watchPathChange();
       var name = FlowRouter.current().params._id;

       var name = $('#card').val();


       Meteor.call('name.update',name);
       FlowRouter.go('/');
   }
});
```

**Server**

name.js

```
Meteor.methods({
  'name.update'( name) {

    Name.update({
        $set: {

          nam: name


        }
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not telling it what to update in the [`Publications.update({})`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-update) - note that you need an selector and a modifier.

It should look more like:

```
Publications.update(
  {_id: "SOMEID"}, <--- missing bit
  {$set: {pub: publication}}
)
```